# Is it possible to insert a video from an add-in using the Office Common API?

Tags: audio, video, ms-office, office-js

I'm developing an add-in for Office applications (primarily Word and PowerPoint) using the Common API for Office, and I need to be able to insert videos into the current selection. In the future, I want to be able to insert audio-clips too.

Currently, I have been able to insert images using the `setSelectedDataAsync(data, options, callback)` method. As far as I can tell, there's no suitable coercion type in the Office.CoercionType enum that supports videos, and I've had no luck omitting the 'options' argument. It would probably be possible to use the Open Office XML format, but it seems like this is only supported in Word. Is there any way to insert videos (and potentially audio-clips too) in both Word and PowerPoint using the Common API for Office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not this is not possible. In Word you can insert the OOXML coercionType, however that is not supported for PPT.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Just to be completely sure - this means that it isn't possible to insert videos or audio clips using the OOXML coercion type in neither Word nor PowerPoint?

Comment: if you have the OOXML representation of such objects you can add them with OOXML in Word. not in PPT.